# Difference between x and &x in c

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between a pointer to an array and a pointer to the first element of an array? In most cases they would be same. Please specify an example when they are not the same. Thank you.

Comment: I just read somewhere they are not but couldn't understand the explanation.

Comment: Good grief, if you "read somewhere" something that is confusing you should tell us what you read and where you read it. Otherwise we're shooting in the dark here..

Comment: It depends, what is your definition of an array? An array is a contiguous block in memory. A pointer to that will, 9/10 be a pointer to the first element in that block of memory. If you mean a pointer to a pointer, then they're different types alltogether

Comment: @RogerRowland Different sizes. According to the explanations given, sizeof(x) contains the size of the entire array whereas sizeof(&x) contains the size of only the first element.

Answer (score 5):

The type is different:

```
int x[1] = {0};
```

`&x[0]` is a pointer to the first element of `x` array and is of type `int *`.

`&x` is a pointer to `x` array and is of type `int (*)[1]`.

But their value is the same because there is no padding in arrays:

```
(int *) &x == x  /* in a value context the expression evaluates to 1 */
```

Comment: You could also point the type of `x` which is of type `int [1]`

Comment: Thanks..! Took me some time to grasp..but happy now!

Comment: Additionally, the representation and size may be different. In a C implementation for a word-based machine, a pointer to an array of `char` could be the address of the word where the array starts while a pointer to the first `char` of the array would need the address of the word and the offset of the byte. So a pointer to a `char` could have a larger size than a pointer to an array of `char`. The value of these representations would only appear to be equal in the C computation model, when they are suitably converted to a common pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

The identity of an *object* is given by the pair (address, type). Different objects can have the same address as long as their types are different, in which case one is a subobject of the other.

This is the case with arrays: The array is an object, and the array elements are objects, and the array elements are subobjects of the array. The first element happens to have the same address as the array itself. Something similar is true for structs and the first struct member.

So if you have an array `T a[N]`, then the type of `a` is `T[N]` and the type of `a[0]` is `T`, and so the address of the array is

```
T (*array_addr)[N] = &a;
```

and the address of the first element is

```
T * elem_addr = &a[0];
```

Since a naked array expression decays to a pointer to the first element under certain conditions, the last line could also be written as `T * elem_addr = a;`, which has the exact same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that when you obtain the reference to an array, it decays to a pointer and `sizeof` can't be used anymore on it to obtain the array size, eg:

```
int array[10];

printf("%d\n", sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
printf("%d\n", sizeof(&array)/sizeof(array[0]));
```

This prints on x64:

```
10
2
```

Of course you will lose any reference to the size of the array even if you convert to a pointer without any use of the `&` operator:

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof((int*)array)/sizeof(array[0])); // prints 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Pointer to an array and pointer to the first element of an array is represented as q=&a and p=a. When you increment the p as p++ it will point to the next element in array but when you increment q++ it will give to the next location to the last element in that array. Thus pointer to an array represents to whole array while pointer to first element in array represents only to the first element in array.

Comment: p=a and q=&a[0] both are same. Array a is pointer to first element in a while &a is pointer to complete array. For example a[5]={1,2,3,4,5} and memory location for a is 1002 then in the case of p=a and q=&a[0] both p++ and q++ will give the value 1004 if int takes 2 byte while for p=a and q=&a, the value for p++ will be 1004 and q++ will be 1012.

Comment: @user3138755 your first line of the answer should be as "Pointer to an array and pointer to the first element of an array is represented as q=&a and p=a." This would solve the confusion. Your explanation was correct though. Thank you.

Comment: @RogerRowland a and &a[0] is the same!! Pointers to the first element of the array. But a and &a (&a[0] and &a) are different in types and sizes but equal in values.

Answer (score 0):

you can print the a and &a, than print a++ and &a++. Through the result, you will know the answer, just try it. a means a element address, and &a means the array address. int a[] = {1, 2 };